# How to display images from path in android?

Tags: android, imageview

I want to display some images in an activity, the number of the images is uncertain. I only have a String[] about the path of the images.

I know how to display one image. Can anyone tell me how to display several images with the ImageView or GridView, please?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You should read this : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GridView tutorial can tell you!

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Instead of the ID-Array, use it with `BitmapFactory.decodePath(String path)`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

See this tutorial, very easy for understand.

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/07/gridview-loading-photos-from-sd-card.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

To get an image from its path, try this:

```
//pathImage contain the path of you image
//get the name of your image from its path
pathImage = pathImage.substring(pathImage.lastIndexOf('/'), pathImage.lastIndexOf('.'));
//get image resource from iamge name
int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(pathImage, "drawable", getPackageName());
//set your image in imageview
yourImageView.setImageResource(imageResource);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9994238/2003486), also, you may try [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to display images efficiently.